# How to encrypt the private key in the config file used by the supersocket

Tags: security, encryption

I am using SuperSocket version 1.6.6.1 and was wondering if it is possible to encrypt the private key
"password="supersocket"" in the server node config below:

```
<server name="EchoServer"
        serverTypeName="EchoService"
        ip="Any" port="443"
        security="tls">
    <certificate filePath="localhost.pfx" password="supersocket"></certificate>
</server>
```

If so, what type of encryption does it support?
What will be the format in the config file for encrypted private key and the encryption it is using?

If I cannot encrypt the private key here what other options I have to make it more secure?